# Adding Windows 10 to Grub (separate NVMe drives)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Firstly, I know that this is a common issue and I've had a look at lots (and lots) of solutions and can't seem to find one that works.

I have 4 drives; 2 NVMEs and 2 HDDs. I have ubuntu installed on one NVMe and Win10 on the other. By default Ubuntu boots first, it loads Grub then the OS. If I press escape then type exit on the CL I get into Win10.

What I want to do is add a Win10 entry to Grub. I have tried various ways of doing this and all return some error. Below is some more info which helpfully will be some help in answering and I'd be very grateful for any input.

Selected output of 'sudo fdisk -l':

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D2B99A34-C0A1-44EB-B90E-393FB67ACD07

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    264191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p2    264192 497696767 497432576 237.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p3 497696768 499130367   1433600   700M Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 499132416 500115455    983040   480M Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 40A17B4D-4941-4598-997C-BB48E968ADFD

Device             Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1      2048   1368063   1366016  667M EFI System
/dev/nvme1n1p2   1368064  79493119  78125056 37.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme1n1p3  79493120 204492799 124999680 59.6G Linux swap
/dev/nvme1n1p4 204492800 500117503 295624704  141G Linux filesystem
```

The EFI partition of the Win10 disk is nvme0n1p3. I notice that this is labelled as 'Microsoft basic data', could this be a problem?

Output of 'sudo blkid /dev/nvme0n1p3':

```
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="ESP" UUID="0857-21A0" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="5f9f79f0-3250-01d5-f808-4f2b2899ea00"
```

Selected output of 'sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list'

```
/dev/nvme0n1
                            (not mounted)  
/dev/nvme0n1p1
                            (not mounted)  
/dev/nvme0n1p2
           ntfs    OS       (not mounted)  01D5325014C4EC40
/dev/nvme0n1p3
           vfat    ESP      (not mounted)  0857-21A0
/dev/nvme0n1p4
           ntfs             (not mounted)  EE0A30400A30085B
/dev/nvme1n1
                            (in use)       
/dev/nvme1n1p1
           vfat             /boot/efi      B7E2-32A6
/dev/nvme1n1p2
           ext4             /              b8146c35-fff3-42c4-b873-1a2d6a84640a
/dev/nvme1n1p3
           swap             [SWAP]         e9c92b6e-a5c4-4317-a4ff-57ee3f8f9c78
/dev/nvme1n1p4
           ext4             /home          39b1e4ee-54d7-469a-94a5-000b7f46a759
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Does  nvme0n1p3 have /EFI/Microsoft folder? If so it should be an ESP - efi system partition. With gparted then add boot flag. Not sure how in Windows. If not run Summary report from Boot-Repair. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  First part of report has not been updated for NVMe drives.

Comment: Absolute lifesaver! The issue was the lack of 'boot' flag. That is one solution I had not come across in other peoples' questions. I just changed the flag in gparted (whilst in ubuntu), I then ran 'sudo update-grub' and it found the boot entry, added it to grub and now works.

Comment: Not sure of the correct thing to do now, I can't mark your comment as the solution. So I've added a quote from you in my answer. Let me know if I should change this.

Comment: Note that grub only boots working Windows, and Windows may turn fast start up which sets hibernation flag with updates. Then grub will not boot Windows but you should be able to boot from UEFI. And UEFI needs to know which partition is ESP which really is defined by some very long GUID partition type. Boot flag is just a short-cut to assign that GUID. So always keep boot flag on FAT32 partition that has UEFI boot files. Only one per drive, but you may want one on every drive.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. I was always able to boot Win10 from UEFI, adding it to grub was the issue. But I'll definitely keep that in mind if I see any strange behaviour after a system update. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @oldfred in the comments:

> Does nvme0n1p3 have /EFI/Microsoft folder? If so it should be an ESP - efi system partition. With gparted then add boot flag.

As soon as I did this I was able to auto-add it to grub using 'sudo update-grub'.

Thanks